# Placing different animations on the timeline

Tags: animation

I'm animating an art project. I've animated multiple objects that form a single fluent animation. I want to duplicate this animation to a different file where I can make one animation seem like 50. It can be compared to a scene with a growing bush with flowers.I've just animated the flower blooming and now I want to have the same flower blooming on 10-30 different twigs.

The first idea was to just isolate the flower blooming - then append this animation and just instance it and place all the instances where I want them. The problem I'm facing is that I can't choose when the animations start, they all start at frame 0 and that's that. Did some digging, finds out that's one limitation with blender.

I've read up on action strips. Sounds cool but it's kind of complicated to wrap my head around and when I watch tutorials it mainly focuses on rigging characters and blending different animations. I still tried but couldn't get it to work.

So what's a good solution for working with multiple animations in blender?  To make duplicates of the flower blooming and redo all the keyframes is useless, there are too many. Besides it sounds like a stupid solution for what i think should be a pretty straight forward job.

Comment: When the original flower is "Appended", not linked, it ends up with it's own set of keyframes.  Similarly when that copy is duplicated, the second copy ends up with it's own but identical set of keyframes.  Any reason why you can't just slide those inherited keyframes further to the right or left in the Dopesheet so they're not synchonised with previous instances?  Relative keyframe spacing (timing) can also be varied, further breaking up similarities.

Comment: Well that is absolutely  something i could do. I just thought there should be a smarter way. But now if I choose this way there is the problem when distributing the flowers over my scene. When I press play the animation jumps back to the world origin. I can't use delta transform because then i need to delta transform all the pieces in the animation one by one. I tried parenting to an empty to delta transform only the empty but then i messed up the pieces in the animation (even if I used keep transformation).